# Is it possible to perform callbacks to the global operators `new` and `delete`?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, heap-memory, delete-operator

Here's what I'm doing:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    int i;
    Test();
    Test(int x);
    ~Test();

    static void operator delete(void * t);
};

Test::Test() : i(1) { cout << "constructing" << endl; }

Test::Test(int x) : i(x) { cout << "constructing w/ arg" << endl; }

Test::~Test() { cout << "destructing" << endl; }

Test::operator delete(void *self)
{
    cout << "deleting" << endl;
    ((Test *) t)->~Test(); // call destructor since it isnt called otherwise
    ::delete(t); // actually delete memory
}

template <typename T> // too lazy to figure out correct type
void callback(Test *t, T fn)
{
    (fn)(t); // delete operator is implicitly static so this syntax is correct
}

int main()
{
    Test *t = new Test();
    callback(t, &Test::operator delete); // deletes t
}
```

I've noticed that unless `operator delete` is overloaded for my class, the previous snippet will fail to compile.  If it's included, it will compile and work as expected (first the constructor is called, then overloaded delete, then the destructor, each exactly once).

I thought of passing the global delete operator `::operator delete`, but that doesn't work either (I get an unresolved overloaded function call).  I can call it without trying to get its address just fine.

Is what I'm doing even possible without defining my own overload of `::operator delete`?

I know that there is basically no use case where I'd ever need to use something like this.  I know that `::operator delete` is not a general use thing, and that it doesn't call destructors....

Comment: Please tidy up the code. You've got two definitions of `operator delete` and a wrongly placed semicolon at the first one.

Comment: So what is your question? You just want to know how to disambiguate the call to `::operator delete`, even though you're aware that calling it will not destroy the object?

Comment: @jrok: oops.  I posted this halfway through playing with it and it looks like I forgot to completely fix it.

Comment: @Praetorian: I'd like to be able to pass a delete operator to a callback without explicitly declaring it, since the compiler will provide you with one in the absence of providing your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Global operator `new/delete` are overloaded functions - you'll need to cast to the correct function pointer type:

```
callback(t, static_cast<void(*)(void*)>(::operator delete));
```

Edit: I'm expanding my answer to clarifiy some things.

It is true that the destructors are not called by the global `operator delete`. It's just deallocation function responsible to return the memory back to runtime. Calling destructors is the job of [*delete expression*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete):

Delete expression first calls the destructors of the object (or objects, if we use array form) its pointer argument points to and then calls the deallocation function (if the pointer being deleted is of class type, it looks for it in the scope of that class first and calls the global one if it doesn't find it).

Another important thing to note is that using a `void*` pointer in delete expression is undefined behaviour, which is what you do in your overload:

```
cout << "deleting" << endl;
((Test *) self)->~Test();
::delete(self); // this is delete expression using void*, UB
```

You're not calling global `operator delete`, for that you'd need to say `::operator delete(t);`. You have a delete expression and the scope resolution operator just tells it to not look inside class scope for deallocation function.

If you change it to this `::delete( (Test*) self);` you'll see `destructing` being printed twice, again UB.

All in all, don't call the destructor inside `operator delete`, it's not its job.

Comment: I should have made the connection that the 'unresolved overloaded function type' indicated that the function was actually, you know, overloaded.  Thanks.

Comment: @Wug Good thing is you'll never make the same mistake again in future. :)

Comment: I'm still unable to get it to work using the implicit `Test::operator delete`.  Various casts aren't doing it for me, and the line that works if there's a definition for it complains about the absence of a definition.  The SSCCE is just the posted code, with `Test::operator delete` undeclared and undefined.  Got any wizardry for this situation?  It's nice that the global void deleter works now, but this is obviously suboptimal because it doesn't call the destructor.

Comment: @Wug *"operator delete is not a member of Test."* Is this the error you're getting?

Comment: @Wug I'm not sure what you mean by implicit `Test::operator delete`. It is, to the best of my knowledge, never implicitly declared for any class. If you don't declare it, you can't get a pointer to it. Also, destructors are called by the [*delete expression*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete), which also calls the deallocation function (either from the class scope or the global one).

Comment: Ok, that helps to clarify things.  I was under the impression that `delete` was implicitly defined for classes, rather like the copy constructor is.  I also had an incomplete understanding of what exactly was happening when `delete` is used.  Things make more sense now.

Comment: @Wug I updated the answer a bit, so this doesn't get lost in comments.